# do i need a visa for a stopover to dubai for less than 7hrs en route to indonesia,

Tags: visas, layovers, uk-citizens, dxb

I have a united kingdom passport. I am going on holiday to Indonesia. I have a stop over in Dubai on my outward journey for 5 hrs, and on the way back I have a 7 hr stop over in Dubai,my question is I would like 2 leave the airport for a few hrs 2 see a bit of Dubai. Do I need a visa? If I do much would it be, how would I go about getting a visa if needed, do I need 2 get one before I go, can I get a visa in Dubai airport?

Comment: You are asking *way* too many questions in one. Moreover most of these have already been answered on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I get this answer in the website www.gov.uk.

**Foreign travel advice United Arab Emirates.**

> If you’re a British citizen, you can get a 30 day visa on arrival. You can extend this for a further 30 days  by visiting an immigration office in the UAE and paying an extension fee. Don’t outstay your visa or you will be fined. If you hold any other type of British nationality (eg British Overseas Citizen or British National (Overseas)) you will need to get a visa from the UAE Consulate before you arrive in the UAE.

https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/united-arab-emirates/entry-requirements